# Not able to access zend framework 1.12 home page

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to use zend framework 1.12 on WAMP 2.5.

I took following steps to create zend project on WAMP:-

1. created a project using 'zf' tool from command line.
2. created an entry in host file.

> 127.0.0.1       zendy.local

3. added a virtual host entry in conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf.

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/zendy/public"
>     ServerName zendy.local    
>   <Directory "C:/wamp/www/zendy/public">
>       DirectoryIndex index.php
>       AllowOverride All
>       Require all granted 
>   </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

4. enabled rewrite module

But when I try to access zendy.local I get HTTP 500 internal server error.

Excerpt from apache error log

> 1. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:13.739450 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3424:tid
>    552] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the
>    server.
> 2. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:15.761937 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid
>    6832:tid 476] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
> 3. [SatNov 15 09:19:15.777562 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3424:tid 552]
>    AH00430: Parent: Child process 6832 exited successfully.
> 4. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:17.574459 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5700:tid 556] AH00455:
>    Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal
>    operations
> 5. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:17.574459 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid
>    5700:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014
>    12:42:59
> 6. **[Sat Nov 15 09:19:17.574459 2014] [core:notice] [pid
>    5700:tid 556] AH00094: Command line:
>    'c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\httpd.exe -d
>    C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'**
> 7. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:17.574459 2014]
>    [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5700:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child
>    process 6780
> 8. [Sat Nov 15 09:19:17.918210 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice]
>    [pid 6780:tid 484] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Have you uncomment `#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` in `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @Indrasinh yes it is uncommented.

Comment: @Indrasinh also I am working on windows 8.

Comment: Have you confirmed that it running on development mode?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, how can i do that ?

Comment: Add this line after your servername in httpd-vhosts.conf `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"`

Comment: Thanks, now virtual host is working but I get an error message "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_View_Exception' with message 'The specified doctype is malformed' in C:\wamp\bin\php\zend_framework\library\Zend\View\Helper\Doctype.php "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64985/discussion-between-user11-and-indrasinh-bihola).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in Production mode so you are not able to see any error just 500 Internal Server Error.

So Just add `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"` in your virtual host it will bring you in development mode.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/zendy/public"
    ServerName zendy.local
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www/zendy/public">
      DirectoryIndex index.php
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted 
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So now zend framework shows you what is the actual error or exception bothering you.